# Google sheets macro to paste what has been copied from an excel sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

This is my first post on StackOverFlow so apologies for any posting errors

I am proficient in excel macros but new to google sheets macros

I currently have a sequence of events I manually go through where I copy some data (rows) from an excel sheet and then jump into a google sheet select the relevant data to be replaced (with the data copied from the excel sheet) and clear it from the google sheet then select cell A7 on google sheets and then simply paste special values only (which is pasting the data copied from the excel sheet) into the google sheet then I update some other data/cells on the google sheet.

Now I want to automate this entire process using google sheets macros, I used the google sheets record macro option and it records everything except the paste special values only, when I look at the macro coding the entire pasting step is not part of the code. I have tried to find a solution, I have tried to modify the code to include/enter the paste function myself without success.

Appreciate any input, code below.

```
 function AutoMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('7:7').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('7:7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());

**THIS IS WERE CELL A7 SHOULD BE SELECTED THEN PASTE VALUES SHOULD OCCUR**
  
spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('2021-03-19');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E:E').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: I think this will be easier to write as code rather than using the record macro. It isn't entirely clear. What is the source range that you want copied into A7?

Comment: I am copying some data (rows) from an excel sheet

Comment: So you are manual doing ctrl+C in Excel and then you want it to access the clipboard and paste it?

Comment: Correct, its actually an automated (macro) process in excel, once the Excel macro has executed, I jump onto the google sheets and currently, I manually select and delete the relevant rows from the google sheets and then select from the google sheets menu bar, EDIT then PASTE SPECIAL then PASTE VALUES ONLY, which works fine as a manual process within google sheets

Comment: I think I've worked out why the pasting is not working within google sheets, it appears that clipboard access is considered a security concern, so it is generally not available from Javascript at all. Further, Google Apps Script runs exclusively on the server side, not the client. As such, it has no access to your computer in any way - files, browser, clipboard, applications, etc
If someone could confirm this I would a appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Now I want to automate this entire process using google sheets macros,

That is not possible as Google Apps Script doesn't include any method to read the clipboard.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros

Answer (score 0):

#### A few workarounds

- Importing the XLSX file into Drive, converting it to a Sheets doc, and then do everything in Apps Script. Apps Script is not so different from VBA.
- Trying to convert the macros using the [VBA macros converter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/macro-converter/convert-files), though as has already been pointed out, you won't be able to access the clipboard with that. Though you can absolutely get and put values.
- If you really want to jump between programs then I would suggest some kind of desktop automation software, but that is probably going to be more of a headache than its worth.

#### Refs

- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Convert VBA macros to Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/macro-converter/convert-files)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is not possible to access the clipboard. However, two suggestions:

1. If you are already going to copy manually from the excel, you could use shift+control+v to paste only values instead of using the edit menu or right-click. I don't see how it would take much longer than a script anyway.
2. Or you could use a prompt like this:

```js
function test() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var response =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Paste values here", "", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if(response.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {return}
    
    var responseText = response.getResponseText();
    var splitText = responseText.split("\t")

    sheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, splitText.length).setValues([splitText]);
}
```

This will open a prompt where you paste the values. It then pastes it to a range starting at A7. It was unclear if you are only pasting a row. If not, this will need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out why the pasting is not working within google sheets, it appears that clipboard access is considered a security concern, so it is generally not available from Javascript at all. Further, Google Apps Script runs exclusively on the server side, not the client. As such, it has no access to your computer in any way - files, browser, clipboard, applications, etc If someone could confirm this I would a appreciate it.

Comment: I think this is true because I've tried using cut/paste actions in a Google Sheets macro and when you look at the code, it seems to be just moving data rather than real cut/paste: 

spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(4, 0).moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());

The result is that incorrect data gets moved.